# How to address 3 parameters in my method program?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, parameters

I'm trying to write a `C#` code for the problem written below, but whatever I do, I can't figure out how to solve the problem. I guess I can't understand why it should be done the way it is asked! Anyways, this is what I need to do: Start a new console application.

- In the Main method, Create a string array of size 5, name the array
  Profile. Ask the user to input their first name, But you must do
  that by calling a method you will write called `GetStringInput` This
  method should require 3 parameters.

  - The first is a string, which is the question to ask the user. (For this first usage, you might pass in a string that says "enter your first name")
  - The second parameter is the `Profile` array
  - The third parameter is an int, the index, meaning, in which location in the array the user's answer should be stored.

    1. First question (First name).
    2. Ask the user for their last name, again, by calling that same `GetStringInput`, but passing in a different question.
    3. Ask the user for their age, again, by calling that same `GetStringInput`,
       but passing in a different question (note that the age will be entered and stored as a string, and not converted to an int)
    4. Ask the user for their favorite color, again, by calling that same `GetStringInput`, but passing in a different question.
    5. Ask the user for their favorite sport, again, by calling that same `GetStringInput`, but passing in a different question.
- Now call a new method called `DisplayProfile`. This method should require a string array as a parameter, and you will pass in the Profile array. Add a `Console.ReadLine();` statement and your Main method is done.
- Now implement the 2 methods that you have been calling, `GetStringInput` and  `DisplayProfile`. The `DisplayProfile` method should pull the information out of the array, and write out the values in a reasonable way.

  Something like, for example Your name is John Smith, you are 21 years old. Your favorite color is green and your favorite sport is tennis.

Now, I have written this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {

               string[] Profile = new string[5];

                    GetUserInput(Profile);     
                    DisplayProfile(Profile);
            }

            private static void DisplayProfile(string[] Showrofile)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} {1}, you are {2} years old.\nYour favorite color is {3} and your favorite sport is {4}.",
                                  Showrofile[0], Showrofile[1], Showrofile[2], Showrofile[3], Showrofile[4]);
            }
            public static string [] GetUserInput(string[] Getprofile)
            {
                string[] Question = new string[5];
                Question[0] = "Enter your First name:";
                Question[1] = "Enter your Last name:";
                Question[2] = "Enter your Age:";
                Question[3] = "Enter your Favorite color:";
                Question[4] = "Enter your Favorite sport:";

                for (int i = 0; i < Question.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Question[i]);
                    Getprofile[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                return Getprofile;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what to do. I appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the problem?  Please read the **How To Ask** guide and edit your question.

Comment: This is homework isn't it? also - the code you put there is functional. Works just fine, the only addition I added to it was `Console.ReadLine();` in the `static void Main(string[] args)` Method below your two custom methods. Stops the console from automatically closing so you can see the output. Which works fine.

Comment: My program works fine, but it isn't what has been asked! I need to get the user data in a method with 3 parameters, 1 string (question), 1 index, and 1 array to store the data. I don't know how to do that way.

Comment: Fair enough, so what have you tried? This is a homework assignment I'm sure, and SO isn't about just giving answers without the person trying to achieve it first. Post some code of what you've done to try and extract that data, use google. You will and can figure this out on your own. I believe

Comment: I have posted the code I wrote above! I'm working on it since yesterday! literally pulling my hairs now! :(

Comment: I'm not asking you to do my homework! I just need some guidance on how to create a method with 3 parameters (string, index, array) to collect user data?

Comment: You pretty much just answered your own question using pseudo-code to be honest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been watching the comments and the other people are right, you should read how to ask the question because it wasn't clear. It does seem some simple Google searches would have answered this question very easily but I will take pity on your hair pulling. Here is an example of what you are asking for.

Sometimes the best approach is to walk away and then come back calm because when you were asking the Gabe how to make a method with three parameters you pretty much answered your own question. See below and good luck, take it slow.

```
public static void Main()
{
    const int TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 5;

    string[] profile = new string[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];
    string[] questions = new string[]
    {
        "Enter your First name:", 
        "Enter your Last name:", 
        "Enter your Age:", 
        "Enter your Favorite color:", 
        "Enter your Favorite sport:"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_QUESTIONS; i++)
    {
        profile = GetUserInput(questions[i], profile, i);   
    }

    DisplayProfile(profile);
}

private static void DisplayProfile(string[] profile)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your name is {profile[0]} {profile[1]}, you are {profile[2]} years old.\nYour favorite color is {profile[3]} and your favorite sport is {profile[4]}.");
}


//Here is where you put the parameters you told Gabe about.
private static string[] GetUserInput(string question, string[] profile, int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    profile[index] = Console.ReadLine();
    return profile;
}
```

## Edit:

Since you brought it up in the comments about the teacher saying GetUserInput doesn't need to return anything you can see how it works. It would look like this.

```
public static void Main()
{
    const int TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 5;

    string[] profile = new string[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];
    string[] questions = new string[]
    {
        "Enter your First name:", 
        "Enter your Last name:", 
        "Enter your Age:", 
        "Enter your Favorite color:", 
        "Enter your Favorite sport:"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_QUESTIONS; i++)
    {
        GetUserInput(questions[i], profile, i);   
    }

    DisplayProfile(profile);
}

private static void DisplayProfile(string[] profile)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your name is {profile[0]} {profile[1]}, you are {profile[2]} years old.\nYour favorite color is {profile[3]} and your favorite sport is {profile[4]}.");
}

private static void GetUserInput(string question, string[] profile, int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    profile[index] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Exactly - He was very clearly on the right track and I just didn't want to take that "eureka" feeling away from him when he figured it out - Those feelings are the best, even for more seasoned programmers. However us it's less about the "it works" but more about "it works well and it's polished". My two cents anyway.

Comment: You should not encourage him...  he'll come back and ask us to write every function for him..

Comment: Ehh. I have seen people quit because they get to frustrated and drop out, when someone could have just helped them once. As for the Ah ha moment sometimes seeing is believing. Again this is why I stated that simple Google searches would have found it but it seems like the frustration was blinding rational searching at this point.

I don't do this often but being in hair pulling state sucks ass. :p

Comment: Thanks you for helping me through this. Well, I was right there, just a bit confused, 'cause English is my third language and sometimes I get in trouble understanding a few things. Besides, my teacher's suggestion got me more confused, 'cause he asked that the GetUserInput method shouldn't return anything! I can't understand how the method should collect data and put it in the array without returning the array?!

Comment: Using a field - jump on google and search for "Fields in C#" :)

Comment: Actually your teacher is correct it doesn't need to return anything. I assumed you hadn't learned about mutations of objects yet.

I will add to the answer the version of it without a return object on the method. One second.

Comment: @Edwin I updated the answer to include what your teacher was saying. The GetUserInput method is mutation the values of the collection object of type string[].

Comment: @Cubicle aaaaaha! That's where I had the mistake! First I wrote a code similar to yours, but putting profile equal to the GetUserInput made me wrong and then I couldn't put 3 parameters in the method 'cause it has to return only 1 value type . I need to practice more. Thank you for your help!